# Workbox Service Worker fails lighthouse audit when I enable Gzip compression

Tags: express, gzip, service-worker, workbox

I've got a next.js website that uses an Express server to do SSR.

I'm using [next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) as a wrapper for Workbox and Next.js.

My site passes the lighthouse "installable" audit *until* I enable gzip compression using [express/compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression). This is the failure I get when compression is enabled (the service worker still exists, is registered, and is the same with or without compression enabled).

> Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url.
>   The service worker is the technology that enables your app to use many Progressive Web App features, such as offline, add to homescreen, and push notifications. Learn more.

I've tried the standard way of enabling compression

```
app.use(compression())
```

I've also tried setting a filter to exclude the service worker from being compressed - same result.

This is my service worker:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "url": "/_next/static/runtime/main-6d31a0ae74beef7a4022.js"
  },
  ... a bunch more of these
];

/**
 * Welcome to your Workbox-powered service worker!
 *
 * You'll need to register this file in your web app and you should
 * disable HTTP caching for this file too.
 * See [removed short url]
 *
 * The rest of the code is auto-generated. Please don't update this file
 * directly; instead, make changes to your Workbox build configuration
 * and re-run your build process.
 * See [removed short url]
 */

importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(

);

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 * See [removed short url]
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com/, workbox.strategies.cacheFirst(), 'GET');
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https?.*/, workbox.strategies.networkFirst(), 'GET');
```

Why would gzip encoding break my service worker?